# Expresão ternaria para atribuição de valor em uma variavel do iReport com problema

Tags: java, ireport

Galera seguinte, criei uma expressão ternaria que com base nos valores de duas variaveis do mesmo contexto (“grupo”), para que me traga uma media. Porém por algum motivo nao esta funcionando e estou com duvida. Segue a expressão e o retorno do iReport.

Error filling print... Error evaluating expression : 
Source text : `$V{QtdViagens_1} > 0 ? new BigDecimal($V{QtdPessoas_1}).divide( new BigDecimal($V{QtdViagens_1})) : new BigDecimal("0")`

Answer (score 0):

Tente acrescentando o toString();

```
$V{QtdViagens_1} > 0 ? new BigDecimal($V{QtdPessoas_1}).divide( new BigDecimal($V{QtdViagens_1})).toString() : new BigDecimal("0").toString()
```

tenha certeza que as variáveis não estão nulas e
coloque Expression Class:   java.lang.String